# Laplace Beltrami operator invariance property

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact two-dimensional manifold with smooth boundary.

If $\psi: M \rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism and if $c>0$ is a smooth function, we need to show that the Laplace Beltrami equation in two dimensions has the invariances
$$
\Delta_{\psi^{*} g}\left(\psi^{*} u\right)=\psi^{*}\left(\Delta_{g} u\right), \quad \Delta_{c g} u=c^{-1} \Delta_{g} u.
$$

My attempt:

In local co-ordinate,
$$\Delta_g f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_{i}\left(\sqrt{|g|} g^{i j} \partial_{j} f\right)$$

We have $\det cg=|cg|=c^2|g|$.

So we have
\begin{align*}
\Delta_{cg} f&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|cg|}} \partial_{i}\left(\sqrt{|cg|} cg^{i j} \partial_{j} f\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{c\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_{i}\left(\sqrt{|cg|} cg^{i j} \partial_{j} f\right)
\end{align*}

How to show last equality equals $c^{-1} \Delta_{g} u$. How to manage partial derivative of $c^2$ in inside bracket.

In local coordinates
\begin{align*}
    \Delta_{g} f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\operatorname{det}\left(g_{i j}\right)(x)}} \sum_{j=1}^{m} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(\sqrt{\operatorname{det}\left(g_{i j}\right)(x)} \sum_{i=1}^{m} g^{i j}(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}} f(x)\right)
\end{align*}
We have,
$$\left(\psi^{*} g\right)_{i j}=g\left(\psi_{*} \partial_{j}, \psi_{*} \partial_{j}\right),\quad \psi^{*} u=u \circ \psi$$
where $\psi: M \rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism.
\begin{align*} g^{i j} &=\left(\left[(\nabla \psi)^{\top}(\nabla \psi)\right]^{-1}\right)_{i j} \\ &=\left((\nabla \psi)^{-1}\left((\nabla \psi)^{-1}\right)^{\top}\right)_{i j} \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
   & \frac{1}{|\operatorname{det}(\nabla \psi(x))|} \nabla \cdot\left(|\operatorname{det}(\nabla \psi(x))|\left[(\nabla \psi(x))^{\top}(\nabla \psi(x))\right]^{-1} \nabla f(\psi(x))\right.\\
&=\frac{1}{|\operatorname{det}(\nabla \psi(x))|} \sum_{j=1}^{m} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(|\operatorname{det}(\nabla \psi(x))| \sum_{i=1}^{m} g^{i j}(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}} f(\psi(x))\right)\\
&=\psi^*(\Delta_g u )
\end{align*}

Any help or hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: We do not have $(cg)^{ij} = c g^{ij}$ because $(cg)^{ij}$ are the coefficients of the inverse matrix of $c \times g_{ij}$. Finding the proper expression of $(cg)^{ij}$ will lead to something in the parenthesis that does not depend on $c$.

Comment: For the pullback, use the fact that $\left(\psi^*g\right)_{ij} = g\left(\psi_*\partial_j,\psi_*\partial_j\right)$, that $\psi^* u = u \circ \psi$, and use the chain-rule.

Comment: @Didier Dear Sir I have updated solution. Can you please have look to that? Thank you so much.